# Can i populate my Model this way c#

Tags: c#

### here is my all model class

```
public class Student
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name Required")] // textboxes will show
        [Display(Name = "First Name :")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "First Name cannot be longer than 5 characters.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name Required")] // textboxes will show
        [Display(Name = "Last Name :")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Last Name cannot be longer than 5 characters.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "DOB require")] // datepicker will show
        [Display(Name = "DOB :")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Dob { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "State Required")] // drodown will show
        [Display(Name = "State :")]
        public List<State> State { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City Required")] // drodown will show
        [Display(Name = "City :")]
        public List<City> City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Language known Required")] // group of checkboxes will show
        [Display(Name = "Language known :")]
        public List<Language> Language { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sex Required")] // group of radio button will show
        [Display(Name = "Sex :")]
        public List<Sex> Sex { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Computer Course Required")] // listbox will show
        [Display(Name = "Computer Course Done :")]
        public List<ComputerCourse> ComputerCourse { get; set; }

    }
```

### can i populate this way ?

```
var model =  new Student()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Dob = DateTime.Now,

    State = new list<State>()
        {
            new state({ID="1" , Name = "test1"});
            new state({ID="2" , Name = "test2"});
            new state({ID="3" , Name = "test3"});
        };

}
```

specially see this code....does it work bcoz i am not before my pc now.

```
State = new list<State>()
            {
                new state({ID="1" , Name = "test1"});
                new state({ID="2" , Name = "test2"});
                new state({ID="3" , Name = "test3"});
            };
```

please tell me if any area need to edit or change in code for model population. thanks

Comment: state needs to be capital, it should work. Why not just wait till you can try it out? you can't do anything if it doesn't work anyway

Comment: This question would fit better on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave out the empty parenthesis when your providing parameters in that way...

```
var model =  new Student //deleted parenthesis
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Dob = DateTime.Now,    
    State = new List<State>//deleted parenthesis
        {
//          new State({ID="1" , Name = "test1"}); don't wrap params in parenthesis
            new State{ID="1" , Name = "test1"},
            new State{ID="2" , Name = "test2"},
            new State{ID="3" , Name = "test3"}
        }    
}
```

Comment: should probably be `,` and not `;` at the states (and capital L in `List`)

Comment: :-) caught me editing - well spotted on the lower case L

Comment: hehe.. actually, `model` is initialized here, so the trailing `;` would be a compiler error. a `,` would work though if I'm not mistaken. You would need a `;` after the last `}`as well

Answer (score 1):

It should be probably like this:

```
State = new List<State>
            {
                new State{ID="1" , Name = "test1"},
                new State{ID="2" , Name = "test2"},
                new State{ID="3" , Name = "test3"}
            }
```

Comment: small typo... trailing parenthesis at the end of each line.

Comment: You don't need any parenthesis' in this, (even after <State>)

Comment: thanks a lot. because my frnd was seeking help and i am not before my pc. so i have no IDE. i just wrote code in note pad. anyway good help. thanks